# .nii to jpeg conversion, coordinates mismatch after conversion

Tags: matlab

I am converting .nii file to jpeg images using [this](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image) matlab tool using following program:

```
a=load_nii('file.nii')
a_images=a.img
imtool(a_images(:,:,image_number),[]) #for checking pixel location of particular image
```

after checking i got different pixel location of desired thing which i got using [MITK](http://mitk.org/wiki/MITK). I tried some rotation and flip operation using `imrotate` `fliplr` and `flipud` but not getting correct result. I know some rotation and flip operation is needed but in which order i don't know. Please help.